# Remove property descriptors in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to remove property descriptors set with `Object.defineProperty`? The `configurable` descriptor can be `true`. Deleting the property and adding it back is one way to do it, but is there a built-in way?

Comment: but if you remove it - you just totally delete don't you? but if your purpose is to leave the property there, why not just set it to null

Comment: I want to remove just the property descriptors, not the values of the properties. I would store the value in a temporary variable, delete it, and set it back. It works in most cases, but it seems "hacky".

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but if (like me) you're monkey-patching objects (instances) with `Object.defineProperty`, you can remove those patches using `delete` - for example, I've temporarily patched `getAttribute` on an HTML element, and `delete node.getAttribute` restores the original function's behavior, thanks to prototype inheritance. (you're deleting the object property - you can't delete the prototype property, which is inherited at run-time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.defineProperty` does not, technically speaking, "set property descriptors"; it sets flags, value, and getter/setter based on a property descriptor. Therefore, it makes no sense to say "remove a property descriptor"; it only makes sense to say "remove a property", or "redefine a property".

The way to remove a property itself is with `delete`. If you then want to add it back, then you add it back.

The way to redefine a property is to redefine it. There is no way to selectively modify some of the flags of the property. `Object.defineProperty` is all-or-nothing. So if you want to change something like `writeable`, then yes, you have to call `Object.defineProperty` again with the entire set of new keys. This is analogous to the problem of how to add a `set` to a property after it is already defined with a `get`. There is no way to just add the `set`. You have to redefine the property with a `get` **and** a `set`.

You can call `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` to get a descriptor embodying the current flags etc., then modify that and call `Object.defineProperty` with it. This will completely replace the previous property (assuming it was configurable). This is not a hack; it's just the way that you would reset the flags of a property. By the way, there is no particular need to `delete`.

However, once you have established a property with the `configurable` flag set to false, you are pretty much out of luck. Not only can you not redefine that property, you cannot even delete it in order to define it anew.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify a property's descriptor if its `configurable` flag is set to false. As [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> A TypeError is thrown when attempts are made to change non-configurable property attributes (besides the writable attribute) unless the current and new values are the same.

So, your *hacky* approach is the only way to achieve this.

That being said, properties are set to non-configurable for a reason and if your application relies on making non-configurable properties configurable, then perhaps there is a code smell in your application.

Comment: But it is also not possible to delete a property if its `configurable` flag is set to false.

Comment: "if your application relies on making non-configurable properties configurable". Isn't that... not even possible?